# What is Maxwell talking about?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

The great Scottish scientist James Clerk Maxwell wrote in 1874 to a colleague:

> I saw conductivity of Selenium **as affected by** light. It is most sudden. *Effect of a copper heater insensible*.**That of the sun great**.

1. What does **as affected by** mean?
2. Does the sentence "*Effect of a copper heater insensible*" mean *"the effect which a copper heater made is now no longer observable*"?
3. What does  **That of the sun great** mean?

source:[popular science](http://www.popsci.com/article/science/invention-solar-cell?amp&dom=fb&src=SOC)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

James Clerk Maxwell wrote:

> I saw conductivity of Selenium as affected by light. It is most sudden. Effect of a copper heater insensible.That of the sun great.

***What does 'as affected by' mean?***

It refers to the increase in conductivity of Selenium when it is exposed to light. As a verb, ***[affect](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/affect)*** means "to change or influence something". If something affects something else, it has an effect on it.

***Does the sentence "Effect of a copper heater insensible" mean "the effect which copper heater made is now no longer observable"?***

Not quite<sup>1</sup>. It means that conductivity of Selenium doesn't increase when it is exposed to heat. Thus, he noted "insensible". The conductivity is insensitive to heat (from a copper heater, according to him).

<sup>1. However, please read StoneyB's comment below. I agree that it is possible to read this "insensible" as "unaware of, to the observer". I read this "insensible" differently, as "the conductivity was unaffected by the effect of a copper heater". Whichever interpretation you choose, you will get a similar conclusion, which is that Maxwell was not able to observe a noticeable increase in conductivity of Selenium as affected by a copper heater".</sup>

***What does 'That of the sun great' mean?***

It means that the increase in conductivity of Selenium when it is exposed to the sun (sunlight) is great.

Comment: +.95 I think OP is closer on *insensible*: it means 'cannot be sensed', i.e. detected or observed by the investigator.

Comment: @StoneyB I think that makes sense, too. I want to be sure about this (so I can edit the answer correctly). I read Maxwell's notes as "the effect of heat was insensible to the conductivity", and "the effect of the sun was great to the conductivity". Re-reading it the way you suggested (which I agree that it's possible) would mean that he noted "the effect of heat was insensible to me (or my observation)", and "the effect of the sun was great to me (or my observation)". (In that case, my answer is only 1 in 3 correct.) Now I'm not sure which interpretation is more precise to Maxwell's intention.

Comment: In modern usage we might write "unsensable" for *not able to be sensed*, as opposed to "insensible" which is probably most commonly used to mean *not capable of sensing*.

Comment: @Hellion: Actually, we'd use ***undetectable*** today, not ***un/insensible/able***. We still use ***sense*** in the sense of ***detect***, but ***sensible*** is almost exclusively used to mean ***rational, reasonable*** (of something that ***makes sense***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers very true, I should have said "if we're determined to use 'sense' as the root".  :-)

Comment: @Hellion: Personally, I don't think this Q should be on ELL at all. It's entirely based on a text which is hopelessly outdated, and which *even when it was written* would never have been considered "grammatical". So I'm going to flag it for migration to ELU, but I've no idea how the mods treat such requests.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The quote itself is quite old, but the OP read it in a magazine article. I personally think that if the OP is trying to understand a newspaper/magazine article, that's "current"/common enough that we should help them to understand here. But the community might disagree, and I'm going to encourage you to bring this one up on meta. Once we graduate, it'll take 5 votes to migrate, but for now mods have to use our best judgement... And in this case mine is saying "I think this Q is okay here, but I'm not sure the community will agree and am happy to migrate if I'm wrong."

Comment: @WendiKidd: Okay, thanks for that. I will get around to raising the issue on meta, as you suggest. My own position, obviously, is that "no longer current" usages (such as ***most sudden*** and ***insensible*** here) aren't really relevant to learners in general, and should be on ELU. But on the other hand, the basic principles relevant to understanding the two usages OP *did* ask about are still current. As you imply, this is an area where it would be good to air the issues and see if we can reach a consensus.

Comment: @Wendi et al.: My 2¢? Based on "What does *as affected by* mean?", if this is where the O.P. wants to ask the question, the question belongs here. We don't base migration on the obscurity of the original, but on the depth of the answer desired.